# Discord.py how to get mutual guilds(servers)?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I spent a good time trying to look this up but I can't find a solution.
I am trying to get the mutual servers(ideally server IDs of the mutual servers) for my bot, but I can't seem to figure it out.
This is what I have:

```
    user = await self.bot.fetch_user(ctx.message.author.id)
    print(user)
    mg = user.profile.mutual_guilds
    print(mg)
```

this outputs the error:

> 'function' object has no attribute 'mutual_guilds'

Can someone please tell me how can I get the mutual guilds?

Thanks in forward for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`profile` is not an attribute. It is async function. Therefore you need to use it like this:

```py
(await user.profile()).mutual_guilds
```